# What is the sequence for tagging commit in git?

Tags: git, tags, git-tag

I cloned a git repo and made some changes.
I have to commit changes and then tag those committed changes. 
What should be the sequence of commands? Is it like: `git clone`, `git add`, `git commit`, `git push`, and then `git tag`?

If not, what is the sequence ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can tag a revision right after your commit or later (after a push). Then, you can push your tag with: `git push origin [tagname]`.

So, yes, your sequence is ok. Take a look at this, for more details: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging.

Comment: If you want to share the tag you need to `git tag` before `git push`. (i.e. the sequence is not 100% correct)

Comment: So tag is applied on commit but not branch, right?